# Short story about a girl killing cancer cells with a video game

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Remembering a short story I read when I was about 8-10 (this would have been 1981-83). I could have sworn it was in OMNI magazine, but it could have been in the Asimov Digest or something else.

The story involves a little girl with leukemia being fitted with a biofeedback controller that allows her to kill her own cancer cells with a video game interface. I remember an illustration accompanying it - little girl's (Caucasian, I think, possibly blonde?) face in profile, wearing a headband with a kind of eyepiece attached. I've been poring over the OMNI archives with no luck.

Comment: Based on the title, I though you were referring to "Do No Harm" by Anna Ibbotson. But it is much more recent (I came across the story in a collection called "Best of British Science Fiction 2018"), the girl protagonist must be more in her teens or slightly above, and it's not her own body the game takes place in, but someone else's.

Comment: I remember an article in National Geographic around this time where there was, in real life, kids with cancer playing a video to kill cancer cells; the difference was that obviously this was just a game, provided for their mental health, to give them a sense of control over their condition.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a try!